# How to upgrade mattermost running with docker?

Tags: docker, mattermost

I'm hosting `mattermost-6.3` via docker. I followed this documentation https://docs.mattermost.com/install/install-docker.html and cloned the repository https://github.com/mattermost/docker then I copied generated the `.env` file (from `env.example`) and with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.without-nginx.yml up -d` mattermost is up and running.

So far so good, but now I'd like to do an upgrade to `v7.4` but I'm finding quite difficult to find a proper documentation on how to do that.

https://docs.mattermost.com/upgrade/prepare-to-upgrade-mattermost.html says what
migrations to execute. `v6.7`, `v7.0` and `v7.1` are explicitly listed, so that
means that I have to first migrate to `v6.7`, then to `v7.0` and then to `v7.1`?
Or can I just apply all the migration at once?

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS idx_posts_create_at_id on posts(createat, id);
ALTER TABLE reactions ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS channelid varchar(26) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
UPDATE reactions SET channelid = COALESCE((select channelid from posts where posts.id = reactions.postid), '') WHERE channelid='';
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS idx_reactions_channel_id on reactions (channelid);
```

And after executing these SQL command in `psql`, then what? The next item in the
documentation is [Upgrading mattermost server](https://docs.mattermost.com/upgrade/upgrading-mattermost-server.html) but
there is no mention her for docker installations. So what should I do? Stop
everything, change the `MATTERMOST_IMAGE_TAG` from `6.3` to `7.4` (assuming that
the `7.4` tag exists, right now I cannot see that as
https://hub.docker.com/r/mattermost/mattermost-enterprise-edition/tags
shows a spinning circle only) and then execute `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.without-nginx.yml up -d` again? Is that all?

Like I said, I fail to find a proper documentation of the necessary steps to
upgrade when you run with docker.

And what about plugins? Do I need to do something specific to upgrade those too or are they automatically upgraded when you upgrade mattermost?

Am I missing something?

Comment: What I plan on doing is making a backup of everything then spinning up a separate instance from that backup and testing changing the version incrementally to 6.7 then 7.0 then 7.1 using docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d over and over and cross my fingers and hope it works.

Comment: @thed0ctor I wanted to do same, just make backup, copy everything at home and try there.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a different version of Mattermost running in Docker:

- Shut down your deployment.
- Run git pull to fetch any recent changes to the repository, paying attention to any potential env.example changes.
- Adjust the MATTERMOST_IMAGE_TAG in the .env file to point your desired enterprise or team image version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).